# Error in C# WinForm Paypal integration with asmx web service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal payments in a .NET 4.0 C# WinForm application doing a DirectPayment (without opening the browser with the paypal site) trought an asmx webservices calling this method from a WebMethod

```
public DoDirectPaymentResponseType DoDirectPaymentAPIOperation(string 
    amountinUSDollar, string creditCardType, string creditCardNumber, int 
    exp_month, int exp_year, string firstName, string middleName, string 
    lastName, string address1, string address2, string city, string state, 
    string zip, string phoneNumber, string CVV2)
{
    DoDirectPaymentResponseType response = new 
    DoDirectPaymentResponseType();
    DoDirectPaymentReq wrapper = new DoDirectPaymentReq();
    DoDirectPaymentRequestType request = new DoDirectPaymentRequestType();
    DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType requestDetails = new 
        DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType();
    requestDetails.PaymentAction = (PaymentActionCodeType)               
        Enum.Parse(typeof(PaymentActionCodeType), "SALE");
    CreditCardDetailsType creditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
    PayerInfoType cardOwner = new PayerInfoType();
    PersonNameType payer = new PersonNameType();
    payer.FirstName = firstName;
    payer.MiddleName = middleName;
    payer.LastName = lastName;
    cardOwner.PayerName = payer;
    creditCard.CardOwner = cardOwner;
    creditCard.CreditCardNumber = creditCardNumber; 
    if (creditCardType == "VISA")
    {
        creditCard.CreditCardType = CreditCardTypeType.VISA;
    }
    else if (creditCardType == "MasterCard")
    {
        creditCard.CreditCardType = CreditCardTypeType.MASTERCARD;
    }
    creditCard.CVV2 = CVV2;
    creditCard.ExpMonth = exp_month;
    creditCard.ExpYear = exp_year;
    requestDetails.PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
    requestDetails.PaymentDetails.NotifyURL = "http://IPNhost";
    BasicAmountType paymentAmount = new 
        BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, amountinUSDollar);
    requestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal = paymentAmount;
    wrapper.DoDirectPaymentRequest = request;
    Dictionary<string, string> config = getConfigDict();
    PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new 
        PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(config);
    response = service.DoDirectPayment(wrapper);
}
```

When it try to make the call to the API, in the last line of the code I get this error:
"Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Invalid HTTP response The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."} System.Exception {PayPal.Exception.PayPalException}.

I had a .NET 4.5 WebForm web application with Paypal integrated in which I had to define this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

in its Global.asax file and it solves the problem for that specific application and I have found I have to use this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;
```

for .NET 4.0 but my question is:

If this would be the solution to may problem, where should I put this line in my code? Because there is no Global.asax in my asmx webservice.

Comment: I'm guessing, but it looks like your "NotifyURL" doesn't have HTTPS enabled. The exception seems to be generated from the PayPal side but it's not certain given the call. Alternatively, the URL you're initiating the connection with doesn't have SSL/TLS turned on

Comment: @DiskJunky, thanks, you brought some light to my problem, I wrote the line just before "response = service.DoDirectPayment(wrapper)" and defined https in the NotifyURL and I am not getting the error any more. Now I am about to formulate another question because I am getting a Failure response and I am passing all the required parameters to the API

Answer (score 1):

Outlining the source of the reported issue above as per the comments in the OP. The exception was thrown because the `NotifyURL` wasn't in `https`.